# insert additional column values(not available in file) in postgresql table using COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, insert, postgresql-copy

Table columns:

```
col1, col2, col3, fname, lname
```

CSV file contains values like:

```
col1,col2,col3
val1,val2,val3
val1,val2,val3
```

I want to add data from csv along with additional data i.e. `col1,col2,col3,fname,lname` in table using COPY functionality of postgres.

Can this be done using COPY?
If not please suggest workaround.

Answer (score 1):

psql \COPY supports reading from program output. We can modify the file on the fly using cat and sed:

`'cat myFile | sed \'s/$/;col1;col2/\''`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary table, modify it then copy back real destination table:

```
# create a temp table with the same structure as dest table, and drop it on commit
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_dest ON COMMIT DROP AS TABLE dest_table WITH NO DATA;"

COPY temp_dest(col1,col2 ...) FROM '/file/to/data.COPY'

# Do update in temp_dest, only affect the data just copied
UPDATE temp_dest set col_x=x where ...

INSERT INTO dest_table SELECT * FROM temp_dest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a list of columns in the [`copy` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

```
copy YourTable(col1,col2,col3) 
    from '/home/you/yourfile.csv' 
    delimiter ','
    csv header;
```

The `header` option tells `copy` to ignore the first row.

Comment: I need to add additional values. These values are not available in the CSV.

Comment: You set the other columns after the `copy` with an `update` query

Comment: Using `copy` only is not possible?

Comment: I need to add a column with default boolean value as `false`, and it worked. No need to add the values in csv file before copying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following workaround, 
I have created a shell script to prefix additional column values in the CSV file.

```
additional_cols="Fred,Solo";#fname,lname
csv_file="filename.csv";
sed -i -e "s/^/$additional_cols\,/" $csv_file
```

once the file is edited, its easy to import values using `COPY` of postgres. Use [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) to `COPY` documentation.